# NVD3 Line Plus Bar Chart timeline

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have to add proper timeline to "Line Plus Bar Chart", meaning dates must be spread across x-axis equally.
For example AAPL dividend history.
[image]
And since AAPL didn't make payment between 1995 and 2012, there should be blank space. So I need x-axis to be spread according to the first and the last date. Something like this: 
[image]
Is there a way to show x-axis fixed on real dates, ignoring data?

or do I need to add 0 values to my dividend_set? This is my data for dividend_set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function exampleData() {
        return [
            {
                "key" : "Dividends" ,
                "bar": true,
                "values" : [

                        [ 547707600000 , 0.015 ] , 

                        [ 555570000000 , 0.015 ] , 

                        [ 564127200000 , 0.02 ] , 

                        [ 571644000000 , 0.02 ] , 

                        [ 579762000000 , 0.02 ] , 

                        [ 587624400000 , 0.02 ] , 

                        [ 596095200000 , 0.025 ] , 

                        [ 603698400000 , 0.025 ] , 

                        [ 611816400000 , 0.025 ] , 

                        [ 619678800000 , 0.025 ] , 

                        [ 627285600000 , 0.0275 ] , 

                        [ 635148000000 , 0.0275 ] , 

                        [ 643266000000 , 0.0275 ] , 

                        [ 651128400000 , 0.0275 ] , 

                        [ 658735200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 666597600000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 674715600000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 682578000000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 690444000000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 698047200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 707374800000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 714027600000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 723103200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 729496800000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 738565200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 745477200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 753688800000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 760600800000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 770014800000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 776926800000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 785138400000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 792655200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 801464400000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 808549200000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 816933600000 , 0.03 ] , 

                        [ 1344488400000 , 2.65 ] , 

                        [ 1352268000000 , 2.65 ] , 

                        [ 1360216800000 , 2.65 ] 

                ]
            } ,

            {
                "key" : "Dividends together" ,
                "values" : [


                            [ 547707600000 ,
                                0.015 ]
                            , 

                            [ 555570000000 ,
                                0.03 ]
                            , 

                            [ 564127200000 ,
                                0.05 ]
                            , 

                            [ 571644000000 ,
                                0.07 ]
                            , 

                            [ 579762000000 ,
                                0.09 ]
                            , 

                            [ 587624400000 ,
                                0.11 ]
                            , 

                            [ 596095200000 ,
                                0.135 ]
                            , 

                            [ 603698400000 ,
                                0.16 ]
                            , 

                            [ 611816400000 ,
                                0.185 ]
                            , 

                            [ 619678800000 ,
                                0.21 ]
                            , 

                            [ 627285600000 ,
                                0.2375 ]
                            , 

                            [ 635148000000 ,
                                0.265 ]
                            , 

                            [ 643266000000 ,
                                0.2925 ]
                            , 

                            [ 651128400000 ,
                                0.32 ]
                            , 

                            [ 658735200000 ,
                                0.35 ]
                            , 

                            [ 666597600000 ,
                                0.38 ]
                            , 

                            [ 674715600000 ,
                                0.41 ]
                            , 

                            [ 682578000000 ,
                                0.44 ]
                            , 

                            [ 690444000000 ,
                                0.47 ]
                            , 

                            [ 698047200000 ,
                                0.5 ]
                            , 

                            [ 707374800000 ,
                                0.53 ]
                            , 

                            [ 714027600000 ,
                                0.56 ]
                            , 

                            [ 723103200000 ,
                                0.59 ]
                            , 

                            [ 729496800000 ,
                                0.62 ]
                            , 

                            [ 738565200000 ,
                                0.65 ]
                            , 

                            [ 745477200000 ,
                                0.68 ]
                            , 

                            [ 753688800000 ,
                                0.71 ]
                            , 

                            [ 760600800000 ,
                                0.74 ]
                            , 

                            [ 770014800000 ,
                                0.77 ]
                            , 

                            [ 776926800000 ,
                                0.8 ]
                            , 

                            [ 785138400000 ,
                                0.83 ]
                            , 

                            [ 792655200000 ,
                                0.86 ]
                            , 

                            [ 801464400000 ,
                                0.89 ]
                            , 

                            [ 808549200000 ,
                                0.92 ]
                            , 

                            [ 816933600000 ,
                                0.95 ]
                            , 

                            [ 1344488400000 ,
                                3.6 ]
                            , 

                            [ 1352268000000 ,
                                6.25 ]
                            , 

                            [ 1360216800000 ,
                                8.9 ]



                ]
            }
        ].map(function(series) {
                    series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
                    return series;
                });
    }
</script>
```

This is my d3.js/nv code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var testdata = exampleData(),
        chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 70, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            .x(function(d,i) { return i })
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
    });

    chart.y1Axis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',05f'));

    chart.y2Axis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',05f')(d) });

    chart.bars.forceY([0]);
    chart.lines.forceY([0]);

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(exampleData())
        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

I guess if it cant be done by some NDV3 function, I must calculate what is average interval between dividends and then check, if there is date within that range and if not, I will add similar date interval with 0 dividend amount. Or what would be the best way?

Comment: Are you converting the x values to `Date` objects before passing them to NVD3?

Comment: I thought nvd3 was already converting timestamp into date format. Does it not? Where can I change that?

Comment: I faced the same problem with Multi Bar Chart, solved by adding 0 values to all dates, have you tried this?

Comment: not yet, I thought there is a ndv3/d3 function that would create proper timeline without adding extra 0 data. But I guess I need to do it like your did. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post answer here. I have not find any function in NVD3 library that would fix this. Just generate dates with zero values in your data.